# How to use Resources.resx to link images

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, resources

I have included an icon file inside my Resources.resx that I'd like to show on a TreeViewItem that is inside a stackpanel.

1)Can .ico files be used for this purpose? Or does it have to be .bmp or jpg?

2)What do you set the source as in XAML? The following code didn't work for me

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Margin="2" Source="/Resources/Folder_Back.ico" />
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding ProgramName}"
     Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can't do that. that worked only in winforms

see this post for more info

[Different way how add image to resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775030/different-way-how-add-image-to-resources)

use the method shown in this post

[WPF image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)

instead

**quote:**

If you will use the image in multiple places, then it's worth loading the image data only once into memory and then sharing it between all `Image` elements.

To do this, create a [`BitmapSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx)  as a resource somewhere:

```xml
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource" UriSource="../Media/Image.png" />
```

Then, in your code, use something like:

```xml
<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImageSource}" />
```

In my case, I found that I had to set the `Image.png` file to have a build action of `Resource` rather than just `Content`.  This causes the image to be carried within your compiled assembly.

Comment: Can I use .ico files for image source?

Comment: yes. just use .ico instead of png. you can even edit it inside VS

Answer (score 11):

Here is a trick to access image in Resource file:

[Accessing image from Resource File in XAML markup](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166550/Accessing-image-from-Resource-File-in-XAML-markup)

First you need to add reference to project properties like this:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
```

And then access it via XAML like this:

```
<image source="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.ImageName}}" />
```

You can use PNG/JPG/BMP as well as ICO file but everyone recommend PNG.

Comment: This doesn't work. Nothing shows up. I tried using it for an icon as well as an Image.

Answer (score 8):

to make the solution of Qorbani work add a converter to the Image Source.Binding!

XAML - Namespaces

```
 xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Properties"
 xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Converter"
```

Xaml - Resource (UserControl or Window)

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
              <converter:BitmapToImageSourceConverter x:Key="BitmapToImageSourceConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Xaml Code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.Import}, Converter={StaticResource BitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Import</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

BitmapToImageSourceConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class BitmapToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var bitmap = value as System.Drawing.Bitmap;
            if (bitmap == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

            var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
                rect,
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            try
            {
                var size = (rect.Width * rect.Height) * 4;

                return BitmapSource.Create(
                    bitmap.Width,
                    bitmap.Height,
                    bitmap.HorizontalResolution,
                    bitmap.VerticalResolution,
                    PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                    null,
                    bitmapData.Scan0,
                    size,
                    bitmapData.Stride);
            }
            finally
            {
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Qorbani's answer dosen't work for image. but I got some error after execute. "staticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property". The solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773610/staticextension-value-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer says it is not possible and the working solution converts GDI+ `Bitmap` types to WPF images. But those conversions are completely unnecessary. The solution is actually really simple:

1. When you add image or icon files to a resource file, the designer picks GDI+ types for them by default:

[image]

2. Just open the .resx file in the XML editor (in Solution Explorer right click, Open With...) and change `Bitmap` and `Icon` types to `MemoryStream`:

```xml
<!--<value>..\Resources\Undo.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>-->
<value>..\Resources\Undo.png;System.IO.MemoryStream</value>

...

<!--<value>..\Resources\Error.ico;System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>-->
<value>..\Resources\Error.ico;System.IO.MemoryStream</value>
```

3. Save the .resx file. If you now open the designer you can find your resources under the *Other* menu.

[image]

Don't bother with 'fixing' `Resources.cs`. When you save the .resx file it will be automatically regenerated with the correct types. The generated return type will be actually `UnmanagedMemoryStream` but don't be confused about that.

4. Usage:

```cs
public static class WpfImages
{
    public static ImageSource Error { get; } = BitmapFrame.Create(Resources.Error);
    // [...]
}
```

```xml
<Image Source="{x:Static local:WpfImages.Error}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First:
Add resources rsx 
then:
add images as images to the resource file and set the image build action to Resource.
Now you can access the images like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.png"/>
```