# XAML don´t know the Resource folder

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I tried to set up a Icon in XAML from the Resources.resx but it cant find the resources.

Code:

```
....
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Admin_Overwatch.Properties"
Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600" Icon="{x:Static
resx:Resources.TitelLogomRand1}">
```

Error:
"The name "Resources" doesen´t exist in the namespace...."

The courious thing is that in the autoformat it finds every icon in the Resources file. I have Rebuild it without any success and tried a new Resource folder also with no success.

Why doesn´t it find the Folder(s) ?

Edit:
I tried this tutorial also without any success, I got the same error, it can´t find the resources....
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22420.binding-to-resources-resx-files-in-xaml.aspx

Comment: Try to set access modifier from `internal` to `public` in `internal class Resources`

Comment: In the properties is the Resource Folder "PublicResXFileCodeGenereator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was to use the Assembly in addition to the normal clr:

```
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Admin_Overwatch.Properties;assembly=Admin-Overwatch"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Admin_Overwatch;assembly=Admin-Overwatch"
```

The Assembly name can be found by 
Right Click on the Project name under Properties --> Application.

But the important part is that it is not possible to load the pictures from the resx in wpf that goes only in win forms.

see here:
[How to use Resources.resx to link images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363834/how-to-use-resources-resx-to-link-images)

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problem. Added a placeholder image to use as default ImageSource in XAML on startup. I created it trough Project+Right-Click->Properties>Resources>Add Resource>New Image etc.
Then got to Resource folder in the project, selected the image and down bellow in properties I just selected Build Action to Resource. And now it works!